# passing variable arguments to listener method in a loop

Tags: web-services, actionscript-3, air, event-listener

I want to pass args while calling service in loop. The problem is 
 1- If I use anonymous function as in following code;

```
for (var j:int = 0; j < listItems.length; j++) 
{
    _service.addEventListener(ResultEvent.RESULT, _anonymous = function(event:ResultEvent):void{
    thumbnailResultHandler(event,listItems[k].ObjectID)
    });
}
```

then, when starts running **thumbnailResultHandler**, pushing the latest value of j, and so latest value of listItems array. Because they are working async.

2- If I use following option to pass args;

```
_anonymous = onClick(listItems[j].ObjectID,j);
_service.addEventListener(ResultEvent.RESULT, _anonymous);
```

in for loop, and here is onClick function

```
public function onClick(n:Number,k:Number):Function 
{       
    _service.removeEventListener(ResultEvent.RESULT,_anonymous);
    return function(event:ResultEvent):void 
    {
       trace( count++) ;//traces 25 times but must be just 5.
    }
}
```

then, when thumbnailResultHandler runs, this method access both I passed values to onClick function and then works 5x5 times instead of 5 times working.

This must work once in each resultHandler , but reading both parameters in every result.

**ASSUME listItems.length = 5**

Any suggestion how can I fix this issue ?

Comment: J never gets the value 4 inside the loop. The problem may be different, can you trace thumbnailResultHandler parameters when called via second way? It might be because you are passing parameters, that are and will not be available when the actual event fires, to the handler, inside an anonymous function. You will get the evt probably, but listItems[j].ObjectID will be unresolved more likely

Comment: @Ihsan when I debug the loop, goes to second line 5 times, and then returns me "throw new RangeError(message);" line of ListCollectionView. Why loop works 5 times while length=4? I'm sure this is as I told, because When I send listItems[3].ObjectID instead, works.

Comment: This is very annoying(for both of us :D ). For loops working wrong way...0123 man... not 01234? Humm... Maybe you deleted an array item instead of splice(index,1) ing it... so the location in the array exists but not the value? I would add an if(listItems[j]==null)continue; to the loop and have a nice life.